# Ordering of R(X) in real algebraic geometry

Tags: ordered-fields, real-algebraic-geometry

I am reading Bochnak, Coste, Roy's real algebraic geometry and the definition of ordering on $R(X)$ is not clear to me why/how can the authors write the polynomial $P(X)=a_nX^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+a_kX^k$ this way (with $a_k
\neq0$ and then proceed to define the ordering)? Is the leading coefficient $a_n$ or $a_k$?

Edit: the definition proceeds as follow. With respect to the above form, $P(X)>0$ if $a_k>0$. Can someone explain why this is well defined? I dont understand the meaning/significance of $a_k$ as it is not uniquely defined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by saying $a_k$ is not uniquely defined? The coefficients of a polynomial uniquely determine a polynomial, and we can definitely ask for the coefficient of lowest degree which is non-zero.

Comment: Exercise for OP: To define an ordering on field $K$, it suffices to define an ordering on ring $A$ such that $K=\operatorname{Frac}A$.